# Grails: Implementing SSO

Tags: security, authentication, grails, ldap, single-sign-on

I'm developing an application with Grails.

Im trying to implement an SSO-functionality. But I can't authenticate the users via windows session, because some of them has another windows passwort as the domain password.

(I retrieve the users via LDAP) So, how can I authenticate them?

Scenario should be following:

1. User goes to the Grails-Site
2. Popup appears where the users has to fill in with his credentials
3. After that, he has never to authenticate again...

Does anyone of you has some experience with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you need SSO for many grails applications a good choice is to add [saml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831331/what-is-saml) support to your grails applications using this [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-saml) and then build an [IdP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider) (there are many in many languages) and connect the IdP to your ldap.

SAML is standard and is the future.

If you need more info about saml check the [saml entry at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language). There you can find links to documentation and software.